# JQuery UI selectmenu not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I'm trying to style an HTML select menu with JQuery UI; but it simply isn't working. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mLqt/3/).
Below are stripped down examples of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="parameterSelectMenu">Select a Parameter</label>
        <select name="parameterSelectMenu" id="parameterSelectMenu">
            <option value="volvo">Temperature Actual</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- A button to show JQuery is working... -->
<button id="clicker">A button element</button>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
$("#clicker").button();
$("#parameterSelectMenu").selectmenu();
```

In Firefox "selectmenu" is reported as not a function...

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render   may help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/9mLqt/6/)
The problem is that you are using older version of `jquery-ui` in jsfiddle demo you have created which does not have support for the `selectmenu plugin`.

so you have to add the latest version plugin files as shown below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```